# Как сделать размытие фона?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на блок, размывался весь фон задний, и фокусировалось на элемент?

Comment: соберите хотя бы блок со зданиями, который размываться должен, добавьте в вопрос [mcve], и спросите, что конкретно у вас не получается

Answer (score 3):

```css
.wrap {
  width: 580px;
  height: 370px;
  position: relative;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1360297/415f2687-c951-45d9-9705-17aeba89f34b/s1200);
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.focus {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: ceneter;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.wrap:hover .back {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.wrap:hover .focus {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="focus">Focus</div>
</div>
```

Comment: и где тут размытие?

Comment: Видать нигде...

Comment: @Air мне понравилось :)

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, Благодарю...

Comment: @Air картинку бы поправить - сдохла ссылка, похоже.

Answer (score 1):

```js
focus = document.querySelector('.focus');
back = document.querySelector('.back');

focus.addEventListener('mouseover', blur);

function blur() {
  back.style.filter = 'blur(5px)';
}

focus.addEventListener('mouseout', unblur);

function unblur() {
  back.style.filter = 'blur(0px)';
}
```

```css
.back {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/green-1072828_960_720.jpg');
}
.focus {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='back'>
  <div class='focus'>focus</div>
</div>
```